# Kafka and Zookeeper with docker image

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, oauth, apache-zookeeper, sasl

I have setup zookeeper with the `bitnami` image which is working fine with the kafka image `confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest` image `ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN: 'yes'`. I am trying to establish the SASL/OAUTHBEARER from the BROKER to Zoo and don't want the ANONYMOUS LOGIN. But, as soon as I enable the `ZOO_ENABLE_AUTH: 'yes'` the Kafka is crashing by saying -

```
ERROR Exiting Kafka due to fatal exception during startup. (kafka.Kafka$)
kafka  | org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoAuthException: KeeperErrorCode = NoAuth for /consumers
kafka  |    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:120)
kafka  |    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:54)
kafka  |    at kafka.zookeeper.AsyncResponse.maybeThrow(ZooKeeperClient.scala:570)
kafka  |    at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient.createRecursive(KafkaZkClient.scala:1883)
kafka  |    at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient.makeSurePersistentPathExists(KafkaZkClient.scala:1781)
kafka  |    at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient.$anonfun$createTopLevelPaths$1(KafkaZkClient.scala:1773)
kafka  |    at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient.$anonfun$createTopLevelPaths$1$adapted(KafkaZkClient.scala:1773)
kafka  |    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:333)
kafka  |    at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient.createTopLevelPaths(KafkaZkClient.scala:1773)
kafka  |    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.initZkClient(KafkaServer.scala:635)
kafka  |    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:221)
kafka  |    at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:113)
kafka  |    at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
```

zkCli is getting connected with `ZOO_ENABLE_AUTH: 'yes'` but, no other clients are able to connect to ZK.

Comment: 1) You need to show your Kafka configs. It wont connect to Zookeeper without auth, if you enable auth 2) Why do you need Zookeeper at all? `bitnami/kafka` doesn't use it anymore, for example. Kafka will remove Zookeeper dependency completely with next major release (within next year, approx)

Comment: Confluent container can also run in Kraft mode. https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/platform-quickstart.html#cp-quickstart-step-1